# Auto fill a field in model via function django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I was searching to find a way to fill a field of a model via a function.

example:

```
def myfunction():
     return a_file
class SomeModel(models.Model):
     a_field_name=models.FileField(value=my_function())
```

I some how was thinking to rewrite the `save()`.share with me your idea

Answer (score 1):

For sure you can add a value to the object in the save method:

```
def save(self, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
    if not self.a_field_name:
        self.a_field_name = f"{self.name} - {self.code}"

    super(MyObj, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well as per my understanding your question you can try it like this:

```
  def Function(self, parameter: int):
    return Models.objects.update_or_create(
        variable=parameter
    )
```

Please reply to this message If the issue still persist.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i want to set the value at the exact time when the obj is created.